# How can I make a dynamic font in a textfield in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, dynamic, listener

I created a JavaFX code that generates a 3x3 matrix with random numbers from 1 to 9.
I want the code to make the text size change whenever I change the window size, I want ti to be dynamic with the window pixles. I heard about using listeners but I don't know how to use them.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        int size = 500;
        GridPane root = new GridPane();

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                
                int num = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
                TextField tf = new TextField();
                tf.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, 50));
                tf.setPrefHeight(size);
                tf.setPrefWidth(size);
                tf.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                tf.setEditable(false);
                tf.setText(""+num);
                

                root.setRowIndex(tf, y);
                root.setColumnIndex(tf, x);
                root.getChildren().add(tf);
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, size, size);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Random Binary Matrix (JavaFX)");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: _I heard about using listeners but I don't know how to use them._ then work through about a tutorial on how to use listeners ;) Here you want to listen to window's width/heigt property.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a listener to `widthProperty()` and `heightProperty()` on your Gridpane. For your case, you could try something like this:

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        int size = 500;
        GridPane root = new GridPane();

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                
                int num = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
                TextField tf = new TextField();
                tf.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, 50));
                tf.setPrefHeight(size);
                tf.setPrefWidth(size);
                tf.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                tf.setEditable(false);
                tf.setText(""+num);
                

                root.setRowIndex(tf, y);
                root.setColumnIndex(tf, x);
                root.getChildren().add(tf);

                ChangeListener listener=(observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    changeFontSize(root,tf);
                };
                root.heightProperty().addListener(listener);
                root.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, size, size);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Random Binary Matrix (JavaFX)");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void changeFontSize(GridPane root, TextField tf) {
        double min = Math.min(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());
        tf.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, min/10));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to register multiple listeners to the same property?

Comment: Yeah I see that you can do it with just one listener:

Comment: repeating: how many listeners do you register to root.width/heightProperty each ;)

Comment: _One listener for both_ wrong - and exactly what I assumed you think ;) hint: you do it inside a loop, actually a nested loop...

Comment: *"One listener for both wrong"*

Unless you got a better suggestion in terms of optimization, I don't know what you mean by "wrong", [because my solution clearly works](https://gfycat.com/sandyhandyallensbigearedbat)

Comment: why do you refuse to count? working or not this is a suboptimal solution (to a concededly suboptimal question) and for some reason I don't understand you don't want to improve it - so be it ..